# MuleSoft Runtime Fabric Deployment on Azure

Tags: aks

I am new to RTF and Azure. I am following the MuleSoft documentation for the installation of RTF in AKS.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/1.10/install-rtfctl

It comes with the following command

sudo chmod +x rtfctl
Now it is asking for my password. I tried everything but not sure which password has to be filled there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your user is not sudo user, its asking for root password. talk to your system admin to give your user sudo permissions